# Google places API RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: google-maps

I know I have to set the credentials I have done so, I have waited about half an hour between credential change, I've tried many domains, ports, and I still get the RefererNotAllowedMapError

These are the values I've set in my API key credentials properties:

https://gist.github.com/onzag/23b01979d9bd99c749d8a998c4fa841d

I've tried no value at all, I've tried even an open api key with no restrictions at all (which gives a different error and says that it's expired); I've created a couple of dozen api keys with different combinations, no luck.

I've tried exact paths, without wildcards, different domains, I've removed the protocol; I've read every single trick I can find online and nothing does the job.

Does anyone have an idea? Do I need to create a new developer account?...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone else struggling with a impossible to fix RefererNotAllowedMapError, it has nothing to do with your credentials, at all, you are forced to enable google maps javascript API even if the development guide says that places is an independent API from maps.

The error is totally misleading there's nothing wrong with your credentials.